# change audio output ports from mic to front

Tags: audio, port, 3.5mm

Lately my front audio jack has died. The microphone jacks still works seamlessly and I would like to remap the front speakers output to the microphone if it is possible. I use Ubuntu and I have Aspire 5741 laptop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called `pavucontrol` that can remap audio output ports, and you could also pick up one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) for a cheap; a usb to audio out adapter. I use these all the time for this reason.